# React-- why do looped state updates precede recursive state updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, iteration

When you click the start button, it starts two counters. One uses recursion and the other uses a for loop. Why does the looping counter block the counting of the recursive counter? Also, why is there a limit for the number of iterations in the for loop?

```
import React from 'react'
export default class Clock extends React.Component {

state = {
    recursiveCount: 0,
    loopCount: 0,
    stop: false
  }

  clickStart = () => {
      this.setState({
      stop: false
}, () => {
      this.startRecursion()
      this.startLooping()
     })
  }

   startLooping = () => {
       for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
       setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
           loopCount: this.state.loopCount + 1
      })
  }, 1)
    }
  }

   stop = () => {
     this.setState({
     stop: true
})
  }

  startRecursion = () => {
        if (!this.state.stop) {
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          recursiveCount: this.state.recursiveCount + 1
        }, () => {
          this.startRecursion()
       })
      }, 1)
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
     <div>
     <button className = 'button' onClick = 
 {this.clickStart}>Start</button>
     <button className = 'button' id = 'stop' onClick = 
{this.stop}>Stop</button>
     <h1>The recursive function has been recursively called {this.state.recursiveCount} times</h1>
  <h1> The iterative function has been iteratively called {this.state.loopCount} times </h1>
 </div>
)
  }


 }
```

Comment: what are you _trying_ to do/what is the _expected_ output?

Comment: @TylerSebastian the expected output is that the recursive and iterative functions do not block each other, because both are counting asynchronously.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdsVgYioqBI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets step through the code:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
```

It loops 1000 times. Thats much and will probably hang the browser for a bit.

```
 setTimeout(/*callback*/, 1);
```

You add a lot of timeouts to the queue. Now the code is done. One tick later, *all timeouts* fire at the same time, and will be executed directly one after another. Thats why the counter directly jumps from 1000 to 2000.

> Why does the looping counter block the counting of the recursive counter?

Cause there is only one thread, and that will be blocked by the 1000 callbacks that all get into the threads queue at the same time. The recursive timeout will also end in the queue, therefore it will only be executed after the 1000 others, which takes time.

> Also, why is there a limit for the number of iterations in the for loop?

There is no number of limitations in a loop, however if you block the thread for too long it crashes to help the client:

```
 while(true );
```

Additionally as chris pointed out, calling `setState` too often in a loop might get you in trouble.

Comment: Everything in your post is spot on, except for your last statement. React does implement a loop limit. In the console you get: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: The counters are actually counting as expected. I don't understand why the for loop happens before the recursion resolves. Here is a demonstration: https://youtu.be/GdsVgYioqBI and here is the github repo: https://github.com/jeremygottfried/recursion-v-looping-React

Comment: @jeremy the answer still holds true (mostly)

Comment: The 1000 callbacks don't all go into the thread at the same time. They are sequentially added. That's why I am confused. Is the for loop just way faster than setState, so that the loop completes before setState?

Comment: @jeremy no, they are not.

Comment: Ok I think I finally understand. The for loop takes up a single spot in the call stack, so the entire loop must complete before the recursive callback begins. I think that's where my point of confusion was. I thought each individual iteration of a for loop has its own place on the main stack, but I'm guessing that's wrong

Comment: @jeremy right, every callback function will completely conplete before next one will be called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
      loopCount: this.state.loopCount + 1
    })
  }, 1)
}
```

as that queues 1000 timeouts *without waiting for the previous timeout to finish*. And, additionally, *is* blocking.

Here's a working codesandbox with what I *think* you're going for: https://codesandbox.io/s/2xy00529jp

I took a little bit of a different approach - I'm keeping track of the timeouts and clearing them on `stop` - I don't think there's anything *wrong* with using a flag (`this.state.stop`), but I find my way a little cleaner. Additionally, I'm using the callback for of `this.setState` - this is super important when doing a large number of sequential state updates where the new state value relies on the previous state value. Take a look through [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more info.

Comment: Yeah I agree that your code is more elegant. I wrote my code to demonstrate the issue of asynchronous blocking because I don't understand the issue. My recursive counter already makes use of the setState callback.

Comment: "My recursive counter already makes use of the setState callback..." not what I'm talking about. There's `setState({ ... })` and there's `setState(prevState => ({ ... }))`. Both have an optional second param that's a callback.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification